# How to check call count per request type with requests_mock?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, python-requests

I'm trying to use [`requests_mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in my tests to mock a function making multiple HTTP requests with different methods. So I do something like this:

```
with requests_mock.mock() as mock:
    mock.get(get_url, text='text')
    mock.post(post_url, status_code=200, json={'foo': 'bar'})
    test_function()
    assert mock.call_count == 2
```

This works fine, however it doesn't tell me which HTTP methods were called. Is there any way I can check that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`request_history`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#request-objects)

```
>>> history = m.request_history
>>> len(history)
1
>>> history[0].method
'GET'
>>> history[0].url
'http://test.com/'
```

You can use something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def request_count(mock):
    r_count = defaultdict(int)
    for r in mock.request_history:
        r_count[r.method] += 1
    return r_count
```

Comment: read more here: https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html